# miniconda UnsatisfiableError on Python version when installing pymol-open-source in Amazon Linux

Tags: python, aws-lambda, conda, pymol

I'm attempting to install PyMol open source in the Docker image `lambci/lambda:build-python3.8` using miniconda and no matter what version of Python I use I get an UnsatisfiableError from miniconda, but each time it says it wants a different set of Python versions, but always excluding my current one.

An example error message is

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
> incompatible with the existing python installation in your
> environment:
>
> Specifications:
>
> - pymol-open-source -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
>
> Your python: python=3.7

which seems clear enough - I need any version of Python **except** 3.7, but when I change Python versions the errors keep dancing around. Here are the Python versions I tried and the versions it said it wanted for each

```
Python=3.8 python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
Python=3.7 (3.7.9) python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
Python=3.6 python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
Python=3.9 (the only one that spit out two sets of dependencies)
  - pymol-open-source -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
  - pymol-open-source -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
Python=3.5 python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
Python=3.7.0 python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
```

Miniconda is from https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
The same `pymol-open-source` package installs using conda on my Mac without any problem.

Anyone know how to solve (or even debug) this? Or, more generally, how to get PyMol available in an Amazon Lambda layer?